# How do I start Etoys from Squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

In the Squeak System Browser, I see that there are many class categories related to Etoys:

[image: Squeak System Browser]

But how do I access Etoys from Squeak? How do I get something like the screenshot shown below?

[image: Etoys]

(Source of Etoys screenshot: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Squeak_screenshot.png)

Comment: In the morph menu, add halo, and then click on the eye button with label "Open a Viewer for me".

Comment: Any more questions?  Or does the answer answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are also Squeak versions set up specifically for Etoys, e.g.:

https://squeak.js.org/etoys/#fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

I think there is easier way than Leandro is proposing.

Just run the *Workspace* from the menu where you type:

`Project enterNewWithInitialBalloons`

Select it with mouse and run it - `Do it` (`alt+d`). Application should start. I'm unfamiliar with the application. To me it looks similar to the picture you show.

### **Edit: how did I find it?**

I searched through the source code.  I have to agree that this is not straight forward.

First I tried to find anything that has to do with `Etoys` project/class.  I tried to find anything that would indicate that you can start it.

This way I found `Etoys-Experimental` package with class `EToysLauncher`.  The word launcher to me sounded like it could be launched.  I looked at the `class` of the `EToysLauncher` where I found `instance creating` protocol where you can find these methods (remember we are still at the experimental package!):

- `#buildGallery`
- `#buildPanel`
- `#openGallery`
- `#openPanel`

If you go through these e.g. `EToysLauncher openPanel` you will get a message `doesNotUnderstand: #latestProjectVersionsFromFileEntries`.  I then started to investigate the `Walkback`.  I tried to check what is the issue here.   I got this message because of the last line `^ Project latestProjectVersionsFromFileEntries:  entries`.

I went to the `Project>>latestProjectVersionsFromFileEntries:` to check what it is actually doing.  In meantime I have inspected the values from the `entries` variable in the debugger.  In the `entries` I could find an OrderedCollection but nothing what would **satisfy** `#('*.pr' '*.pr.gz' '*.project')` from the method.  So I thought to myself, that perphaps the Project itself could satisfy it.

I went to the `Project class` and protocol `Etoys-Squeakland-instance creation` where I found two methods `#enterNew` and `#enterNewWithInitialBalloons`.

The `#enterNew` gives `doesNotUnderstand: #newMorphicOn:` so I skipped that one and tried the `#enterNewWithInitialBalloons`, which worked and since it is in the protocol `Etoys-Squeakland-instance creation` I came to the conclusion it has create Etoys-Squeakland new instance.

### **Edit: Show shared flaps?**

Yes, you can activate the flaps also via *Show shared flaps*.

There is, however, quite a difference between running the `Project enterNewWithInitialBalloons` and Showing the shared flaps via Preferences.

If you start the Etoys via the `Project enterNewWithInitialBalloons` you will start completely new project (your currently opened windows will be hidden).  To see your previous windows you need to either *Porojects/Enter Project* and switch to the *HomeProject* or you have to close the newly opened project via *Projects/Close This Project*.

The source that shows it is:

```
enterNewWithInitialBalloons
    | newP |
    newP := MorphicProject new.
    newP world addMorph: (DoCommandOnceMorph new extent: 1@1; actionBlock: [SugarNavigatorBar putUpInitialBalloonHelp]; yourself).

    newP enter.
```

This creates new `MorphicProject` and to this project it adds new `Morph`.

On the other hand, if you start it with *Preferences/Show shared flaps* the flaps will be just added to your current environment without creating a new project.

The source that shows it is: `Preferences class >>sharedFlapsSettingChanged`

```
sharedFlapsSettingChanged
    "The current value of the showSharedFlaps flag has changed; now react"

    self showSharedFlaps  "viz. the new setting"
        ifFalse:        
            [Flaps globalFlapTabsIfAny do:
                [:aFlapTab | Flaps removeFlapTab: aFlapTab keepInList: true]]

        ifTrue:
            [Smalltalk isMorphic ifTrue:
                [self currentWorld addGlobalFlaps]]
```

The `self currentWorld addGlobalFlaps` adds the flaps to the `currentWorld`.  The `PasteUpMorph>>addGlobalFlaps` creates new PasteUpMorph and adds it.

You can also notice the difference also in the menu bar title *Untitled* vs. *HomeProject*.

Comment: How did you find `Project enterNewWithInitialBalloons`? It seems like an obscure incantation. There is no comment in its source code to describe what it does.

Comment: @Flux I have found it via source code search.  I'll try to explain how I found it in the answer ...

Comment: I noticed that I could achieve the same effect as `Project enterNewWithInitialBalloons` by enabling "Show shared flaps" in the Preferences Browser. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ac2F.png

Comment: @Flux I did not know of this settings, but looking on the source code there is a difference.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Squeak, you can choose open the Extras menu in the world main docking bar and tick "set etoys mode".